# Change the only row table color when i click the checkbox

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table like this.

```
    <table>
      <tr class="rowA baris">
       <td>A<td>
       <Td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rowB baris">
       <td>B<td>
       <Td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Then, I want the result like this
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvugw.png)

I want the row where the checkbox I checked change the CSS background color to light grey. 
How can I do it?

Currenly use this JQuery :

```
  $('.checkbox').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

                $('.baris').attr('style', 'background-color: lightgrey;');
            }
        });
```

but all the row become light grey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the correct row

```js
$('.checkbox').click(function () {
     var backgroundColor = $(this).is(":checked") ? "lightgrey;" : "";
     $(this).closest('tr').attr('style', 'background-color: '+ backgroundColor +'');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr class="rowA baris">
       <td>A<td>
       <Td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rowB baris">
       <td>B<td>
       <Td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider using `.addClass()` or `.toggleClass()`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".baris input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
    } else {
      $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("highlight");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.highlight {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="rowA baris">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowB baris">
    <td>B</td>
    <td>
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowC baris">
    <td>C</td>
    <td>
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowD baris">
    <td>D</td>
    <td>
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowE baris">
    <td>E</td>
    <td>
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This way you can use class names and keep consistent across all elements of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just Pure Html, Inline javascript and CSS

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="closest('tr').classList.toggle('table-row-selected')">
</td>
```

```
.table-row-selected{
  background-color:#eee !important;
}
```